# FPDF section breaks

Tags: php, fpdf

I have an array of elements in the following format:

```
Array ( [rno] => 6 [first_name] => John [last_name] => Doe [gender] => Male [date_of_birth] => 1982-11-01 )
```

Is there any way to do a section break to show these values in 2 columns in the page. I do not want to do a page break, as there are more sections coming below these data.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! what have you tried so far? and you should add more details with your desired output

Comment: here is the tutorial for add column http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto4.htm

Comment: I have already gone through this. However it breaks the whole page. Not just a section of a page. I also tried to do using tables. However, my array format does not let me add a table as well.

Comment: I want the data to be presented in columns, like rno, first name and last name in one column, gender and date of birth in the next column